# close 1 javascript tab when another opens

Tags: javascript, web

Im new to javascript and using and editing code found online.

So far I have this which works.

```
 <script language="javascript">
 function welcome() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "welcome";
    } else {
        ele.style.display = "welcome";
        text.innerHTML = "Planning Statements";
        document.getElementById("toggleText1").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("toggleText2").style.display = 'none';
    }
}

function welcome1() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText1");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText1");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "welcome 1";
    } else {
       ele.style.display = "block";
       text.innerHTML = "welcome1";
       document.getElementById("toggleText").style.display = 'none';
       document.getElementById("toggleText2").style.display = 'none';
    }
}

function welcome2() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText2");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText1");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "welcome 2";
    } else {
       ele.style.display = "block";
       text.innerHTML = "welcome2";

    }
}
    </script>

                    <li style="text-align:left; margin-left:5px;"><a id="displayText" href="javascript:welcome();">welcome</a></li>
                    <li style="text-align:left; margin-left:5px;"><a id="displayText1" href="javascript:welcome1();">welcome 1</a></li>
                    <li style="text-align:left; margin-left:5px;"><a id="displayText2" href="javascript:welcome2();">welcome 2</a></li>

    <div id="toggleText" style="display: none">
    <p>Welcome World!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="toggleText1" style="display: none">
    <p>Welcome World again!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="toggleText2" style="display: none">
    <p>Welcome World again wow!</p>
    </div>
```

For me that works. When you hit welcome it displays welcome world. When you hit welcome 1....it keeps welcome world and then also displays welcome world again.

Is there anyway for me to close function welcome if function welcome 1 opens.

Comment: This code has to be getting called or getting attached to an event-handler somewhere but it's not clear where.  All your script tag does is define two functions. Where are `welcome();` and `welcome1();` or perhaps `document.getElementById('toggleText')` + a bunch more stuff? Look for the HTML where it's clicked or .js file or an html `onclick="toggleText()"` attribute which you should avoid using when you know more.

Comment: You are showing me two functions which are never fired or referenced by something that might fire them and two divs with paragraph tags inside them that will not appear because of the style attributes set. Nothing is happening here. It can't be all there is to it if something is actually happening dynamically which is what I assume you mean by "works." Are you looking at server code? Do a view-source in the browser. That's where the HTML that's actually built and served can be seen in full.

Comment: Please use some indentation and post all the relevant code in order to get better and faster answers.

Comment: sorry erik. i thought i mentioned the functions but i didnt :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<script language="javascript">

function welcome() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "Welcome";
    } else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "Welcome";
        document.getElementById("toggleText1").style.display = 'none';
    }
}

function welcome1() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText1");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText1");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "Welcome 1";
    } else {
       ele.style.display = "block";
       text.innerHTML = "Welcome 1";
       document.getElementById("toggleText").style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>

<div id="toggleText" style="display: none">
<p>Welcome World!</p>
</div>
<div id="toggleText1" style="display: none">
<p>Welcome World again!</p>
</div>
```

What you have to is when you hide show an element, make sure you hide the other one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It did it for me. Just one last question, let say I have another function called welcome2. Which does the same as the other 2 functions and has toggletext2 and displaytext2. 

where you have the hiding part...i tried this for welcome and welcome1:

document.getElementById("toggleText1").style.display = 'none';
 document.getElementById("toggleText2").style.display = 'none';

But I had no luck with hiding it. Changed my original code too if that helps understanding

Comment: It's the same concept, you just need to fetch the elements from with getElementById and set the "style.display = 'none'". When you add a new one, just remember to also add them in the first two functions. BTW: don't forget to accept the answer if it has helped you